# cordova-plugin-crop error on cropping 404

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, crop

I am using Ionic 2 and [cordova-plugin-crop](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop) to crop an image.

If I **take a photo** (`pictureSourceType === navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA`), the cropping works fine, but if I **pick an image from a folder** (`pictureSourceType === navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM`), and try crop it, I get:

> error on cropping 404

Here is my code:

```
takeThePhoto(pictureSourceType: any) {
    let options = {
        sourceType: pictureSourceType,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: 720,
        correctOrientation: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    }
    if (pictureSourceType === navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM) {
        options.correctOrientation = false;
    }
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageURI) => {
        window['plugins'].crop.promise(imageURI, {
            quality: 75
        }).then(newPath => {
            alert('newPath = ' + newPath);
            return this.toBase64(newPath).then((base64Img) => {
                this.base64Image = base64Img;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
                alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        },
            error => {
                console.error("CROP ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
                alert("CROP ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            ).catch((error) => {
                console.error("ERROR imageURI -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
                alert("ERROR imageURI: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    },
        error => {
            // console.error("CAMERA ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
            // alert("CAMERA ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    ).catch((error) => {
        console.error("ERROR getPicture -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
        alert("ERROR getPicture: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already would have imported 'Camera' from 'ionic-native', try to replace:

```
  navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
```

with

```
Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
```

And also, try to replace

```
window['plugins'].crop
```

with

```
import { Crop } from 'ionic-native';
Crop.crop(.... )
```

There is ionic2 usage example in plugin's github, if that helps:
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestions. I think the code is a little neater, but I still have the same 404 issue when trying to crop a selected file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, following the link you sent, now works.  Thank you for your help.